# Percentage values not summing upto 100

Tags: d3.js

The bar graphs that i have set up in fiddle here, show percentages but for some values, the percentages are not summing upto 100. Like in this example it is showing, 97%,2% and 2%,which exceeds 100.
Where am i going wrong?
[working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c74eoo2b/7/)

I am appending text using this-

```
 sets.append("rect")
                .attr("class","global")
                .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand()/2)
                .attr('y', function(d) {
                    return yScale((d.global/total)*100);
                })
                .attr("height", function(d){
                    return h - yScale((d.global/total)*100);
                })
                .attr('fill', function (d, i) {
                return color(d.global);
                }) 
                .append("text")
                .text(function(d) {
                    return commaFormat((d.global/total)*100);
                })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are rounding the percentage values. Just change your label format from

```
var commaFormat = d3.format(".0%");
```

to

```
var commaFormat = d3.format(".1%");
```